# ES6 syntax error with babel-loader (webpack)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, react-chartjs

Trying to make a simple graph using [storm-react-diagrams](https://www.npmjs.com/package/storm-react-diagrams)

Not Completely sure how to solve this.
**Error**:

```
ERROR in ./src/diagram.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , (31:9)

  29 |   // link the ports
  30 |   let link1 = port1.link(port2);
> 31 |   (link1 as DefaultLinkModel).addLabel("Hello World!");
     |          ^
  32 | 
  33 |   //4) add the models to the root graph
  34 |   model.addAll(node1, node2, link1);
```

`diagram.jsx` is exactly the same as [this](http://www.projectstorm.io/react-diagrams/?selectedKind=Simple%20Usage&selectedStory=Simple%20example&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=1&addonPanel=storybook%2Fcode%2Fpanel)

Am i missing some kind of fancy es6 syntax here or what?
This is what my [webpack.config](https://ghostbin.com/paste/5de5w) looks like.

Comment: `link1 as DefaultLinkModel` this looks like typescript to me. I'm almost sure babel6 can't transpile it. Just replace it with `link1.addLabel...` or configure webpack to use typescript loader https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `as` keyword comes from [TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org/), not ES2015. It's used for casting variables from one type to another - that wouldn't make sense in plain JavaScript, which doesn't have compile-time types!

If you want to use TypeScript in your application, you'll need a TypeScript Webpack loader (such as [`ts-loader`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) or [`awesome-typescript-loader`](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader)), and to rename your file to a `.tsx` extension.

Alternatively, if you're not interested in using TypeScript, you should just be able to replace `(link1 as DefaultLinkModel)` with `link1` and have things work as expected.

Comment: typescript loader is doing the job, getting different errors now though, but they are solvable, thanks man.

Comment: @ssj.luffy: No problem!